# The system freezes a lot and dmesg gives an error in Nvidia drivers

Tags: gnome, nvidia, kernel, xorg, xserver

I faced constant system freezing in Ubuntu under both Unity and Gnome shell. So I came to Arch. In Arch also I'm facing the same issue. I tried many things in these forums but nothing helped. Please help me. The system hangs constantly and the mouse barely moves. When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> it takes several minutes to go to the terminal and then I can reboot. Please help. Here's the output of dmesg :

```
[    6.796717] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    6.797189] acpi device:43: registered as cooling_device9
[    6.797336] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7
[    6.799421] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.805849] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    6.806853] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.806861] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.806865] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.806869] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.806871] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.806874] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.806876] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[    6.811272] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
[    6.811890] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20130102 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    6.811899] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  331.38  Wed Jan  8 19:32:30 PST 2014
[    6.838317] type=1400 audit(1398926357.773:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=393 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.838325] type=1400 audit(1398926357.773:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=393 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.838330] type=1400 audit(1398926357.773:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=393 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.838816] type=1400 audit(1398926357.773:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=393 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.838823] type=1400 audit(1398926357.773:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=393 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.839087] type=1400 audit(1398926357.773:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=393 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.842069] i915 0000:00:02.0: enabling device (0006 -> 0007)
[    6.843996] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    6.844001] checking generic (f1000000 300000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
[    6.859946] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    6.872309] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[    6.881353] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
[    6.903318] kvm: disabled by bios
[    6.918282] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    6.938776] kvm: disabled by bios
[    6.947512] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.947523] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    6.947525] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    6.970187] [drm] Wrong MCH_SSKPD value: 0x16040307
[    6.970189] [drm] This can cause pipe underruns and display issues.
[    6.970191] [drm] Please upgrade your BIOS to fix this.
[    6.984295] i915 0000:00:02.0: No connectors reported connected with modes
[    6.984297] [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes - going 1024x768
[    6.985118] checking generic (f1000000 300000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
[    6.986601] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb1: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[    6.986604] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[    6.986623] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    7.025551] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[    7.027537] asus_wmi: Initialization: 0x0
[    7.027561] asus_wmi: BIOS WMI version: 0.9
[    7.027611] asus_wmi: SFUN value: 0x0
[    7.028033] input: Eee PC WMI hotkeys as /devices/platform/eeepc-wmi/input/input9
[    7.033210] asus_wmi: Backlight controlled by ACPI video driver
[    7.072351] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.072488] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    7.095533] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x1c/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
[    7.095538]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.095540]    hp_outs=1 (0x1d/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[    7.095541]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[    7.095543]    dig-out=0x20/0x0
[    7.095544]    inputs:
[    7.095546]      Rear Mic=0x1a
[    7.095548]      Front Mic=0x1e
[    7.095549]      Line=0x1b
[    7.108797] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input15
[    7.108922] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    7.109033] input: HDA Intel PCH Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input13
[    7.109141] input: HDA Intel PCH Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input12
[    7.109275] input: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[    7.109401] input: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
[    7.109962] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.110018] hda_intel: Disabling MSI
[    7.110024] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle VGA-switcheroo audio client
[    7.110056] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling 64bit DMA
[    7.113372] hda-intel 0000:01:00.1: Enable delay in RIRB handling
[    7.542846] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
[    7.542905] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
[    7.542946] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[    7.957172] EXT4-fs (sda3): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    8.680212] EXT4-fs (sdb5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.790312] EXT4-fs (sda4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    8.809947] [drm] Enabling RC6 states: RC6 on, RC6p off, RC6pp off
[    8.871639] init: failsafe main process (745) killed by TERM signal
[    8.953226] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[    8.953244] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    8.953246] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.953253] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.953256] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.953260] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.957502] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.957505] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.957516] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    8.969666] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    8.969676] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    8.969681] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    9.017952] type=1400 audit(1398926359.957:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=873 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.017961] type=1400 audit(1398926359.957:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=873 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.018419] type=1400 audit(1398926359.957:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=873 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.024553] init: cups main process (885) killed by HUP signal
[    9.024566] init: cups main process ended, respawning
[    9.059860] type=1400 audit(1398926359.997:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=928 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    9.184063] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[    9.184089] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[    9.184110] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.184333] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    9.359574] init: nvidia-prime main process (1000) terminated with status 127
[    9.503728] init: gdm main process (1053) killed by TERM signal
[    9.559034] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[   10.104818] NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
[   10.104821] NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
[   10.104823] NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
[   10.104825] NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
[   10.104826] NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
[   10.271648] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   10.278373] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1155) terminated with status 1
[   10.278384] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   11.324684] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link up
[   11.324691] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   11.759991] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1663) terminated with status 1
[   22.134770] audit_printk_skb: 150 callbacks suppressed
[   22.134775] type=1400 audit(1398926373.085:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/pubudu/SSD/home/.config/libaccounts-glib/accounts.db" pid=2117 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="rw" denied_mask="rw" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.134846] type=1400 audit(1398926373.085:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/pubudu/SSD/home/.config/libaccounts-glib/accounts.db" pid=2117 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.141819] type=1400 audit(1398926373.093:64): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/pubudu/SSD/home/.config/dconf/user" pid=2117 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   22.649441] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:22:f8:f6:c3:4c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=765 PROTO=2 
[   31.299568] type=1400 audit(1398926382.257:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/pubudu/SSD/home/.config/dconf/user" pid=2117 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   31.299716] type=1400 audit(1398926382.257:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/pubudu/SSD/home/.local/share/telepathy/mission-control/accounts.cfg" pid=2117 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   31.300963] type=1400 audit(1398926382.261:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/home/pubudu/SSD/home/.local/share/telepathy/mission-control/accounts-goa.cfg.I1OBFX" pid=2117 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[   37.575101] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:22:f8:f6:c3:4c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=778 PROTO=2 
[   39.050745] type=1400 audit(1398926390.013:68): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=3253 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   39.050752] type=1400 audit(1398926390.013:69): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3253 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   39.051093] type=1400 audit(1398926390.013:70): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=3253 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   52.500762] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:22:f8:f6:c3:4c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=791 PROTO=2 
[   67.426342] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:22:f8:f6:c3:4c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=804 PROTO=2 
[   67.449510] EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   82.352044] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:22:f8:f6:c3:4c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=817 PROTO=2 
[   84.876854] EXT4-fs (sdb8): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   97.277665] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=01:00:5e:00:00:01:54:22:f8:f6:c3:4c:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=28 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=830 PROTO=2 
[  106.432985] NVRM: GPU at 0000:01:00: GPU-3840b413-5a51-9da2-923a-a4cbb4a5005e
[  106.432995] NVRM: Xid (0000:01:00): 31, Ch 00000005, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
[  106.436635] NVRM: Xid (0000:01:00): 31, Ch 00000005, engmask 00000101, intr 10000000
```

**Note:** Before marking this as duplicate please note that I already know how to unfreeze the system after it freezes (Last time I posted a question like this you marked it as duplicate and redirected to a post which tells how to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. I know how to do that. )

What I need to know is how to prevent the freezing before it freeze and why is it freezing?

Comment: According to the NVIDIA docs, Xid 31 is a "GPU memory page fault", and could be a driver or application problem. http://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/xid-errors/index.html

Comment: I suggest the following: change the video driver at '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' to 'vesa'. This will make video card function the simplest way, and you can check if it corrects the problem or not. If there is no freeze anymore, the original video driver you are using has problems; otherwise, the problem is elsewhere and you can check other things.

Comment: I even tried Nvidia 304,331, 337 (even downloaded from Nvidia). Is it a kernel or Xorg problem?

Comment: I have similar issues and they seem related to memory usage and swapping to disk. I am always controlling the memory usage by gnome itself and google chrome, as tehre are memory leaks around that help reaching the maximum available memory when you keep your machine running for long.

Comment: My system wasn't running for that long :(

Comment: Do you experience this same problem with the live usb?

Comment: With the live usb.. with the open source drivers the system is very slow... Nothing's smooth... really slow

Answer (score 0):

I would start with checking up these:

```
[    6.805849] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[    6.806853] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.806861] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.806865] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.806869] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.806871] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[    6.806874] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[    6.806876] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
```